# Visual Studio Unable to Copy File ...Access to the Path is Denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am unable to build my project when the Solution Configurations dropdown is set to 'Test'.  Multiple errors appear, most of which read 'Unable to copy file [File location] to [copy file location] Access to the path [copy file location] is denied.
I have already checked or attempted the following, and the issue is still unresolved:

- The latest version of Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform NuGet package is installed
- The solution has been restarted
- Clean and Rebuild has been attempted
- This only occurs with the Solution Configuration is set to the Configuration 'TEST', so this should not be an issue with anti-virus software
- I have updated to the latest version of Visual Studio as of 8/24/2018
- I have unchecked the read only attribute on the folder (it resets to read only each time)
- This does not occur when I change the Solution Configuration to Release or Debug
- Deleting the files in the bin/Test folder
- taskkill /F /IM VBCSCompiler.exe /T
- I have tried running Visual Studio as an Admin
- I have reproduced this error on a second machine using the same code from the same TFS repository

Comment: Did you try running VS as admin?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include in my list that I have tried running Visual Studio as an Admin

Comment: Since `TEST` isn't a standard configuration, we can't be expected to know much about it or what it may entail. We really need an MCVE. In this case, we need a set of steps - start from VS running with no solution loaded, create *new* projects and get us to the point where we have a TEST configuration and can see these errors.

Comment: If you manually go to the build folder (for TEST) can you access it? can you access the files there?

Comment: It might be because the file your trying to write already open in another program like Notepad.

Comment: I deleted all the files in the ...bin/Test folder some time ago, in hopes that this might solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I clicked properties, added Full Control and Modify permissions for users, and then did a clean and rebuild on my project.  I did this at the folder level, and parent folder levels before the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon what you have provided, to me it seems like a permissions/access issue.

1. Are you logged in as a Local Admin? If not you may want to get elevated privileges or see if you have other security related items holding you back (e.g. group policy coming down that may be inhibiting you etc).
2. Speaking of elevate privileges, have you tried right clicking on the Visual Studio exe and doing "Run As Admin"? This may help as well.
3. You could also download ProcMon (Process Monitor) and do a trace while you are trying to build. This may provide answers to what is going on.
   ProcMon is now owned by Microsoft (used to be SysInternals, but they got bought by MS many moons ago) --- I would download it, run a trace, then do a filter for "Access Denied" for the results to see what you may not have access to.
4. Perhaps try logging in as a different user to see if that helps?

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Very usefull!! in my case i used ProcMon, and then I discovered it was Sophos detecting a ML PUA thread. Still working on this.

Answer (score 2):

For me worked the following:

```
Project / Properties / Build:

Change Output path to another folder, build, then restore your original path.
```